# What does //# do in Java? In my IDE it turns pink, but I can't find it online anywhere

Tags: java, ide, comments

In my IDE(BlueJ), a comment(//COMMENT) turns grey. A multi line Comment(/* COMMENT*/) turns green, and a Documentation Comment(/**COMMENT*/) Turns blue. While working on a basic RPG Engine in Java, I discovered that typing //#COMMENT will turn pink. I cannot find anywhere on the internet anything about this combination of characters. Could someone explain what the has does to the comment to warrant the IDE distinguishing it from other comments?(Probably a stupid question, sorry.)

Comment: It might be similar to how IDEs will highlight `// TODO` or `// FIXME`. They don't mean anything to the language but do to the developers.

Comment: Seems like a legit question to me. I've certainly seen worse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the BlueJ Reference Documentation](https://eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~norman/SE-pages%202003-04/Labs/BlueJ-reference.pdf):

> **4.7** **Make Stand-out comments**
>
> Sometimes it is useful to make a location in your source code stand
>   out. For example, if you are a teacher, and you want to give students
>   a half-implemented class and mark the places where they should enter
>   code, you want them to find those places easily. Or you want to leave
>   notes for yourself marking sections of unfinished work. You can use
>   stand-out comments for this. Stand out comments start with the symbols
>   /*# (that is: a normal comment symbol followed by a hash sign), for
>   example:
>
> ```
> public int getTotal()
>  {
>  /*# insert your code here */
>  }
> ```
>
> The only difference between normal comments and stand-out comments is
>   that they are displayed in a different colour (pink) in BlueJ's
>   editor. The actual colour can be changed by editing the file
>   'moe.defs'.